# the XPath id('J_SC_header')/header/div[2]//span[1]/a[@data-val='ma_signin']

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

The error indicates that the script timed out while waiting for the element to become visible. It seems that even after waiting for 120 seconds, the element specified by the XPath id('J_SC_header')/header/div[2]//span[1]/a[@data-val='ma_signin'] did not appear on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot assist you without seeing your HTML page source (it can be obtained using either [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or [WebDriver.getPageSource()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource()) function)

You can use the aforementioned browser developer tools to validate your XPath query beforehand.

One possible piece of advice I can provide is using a simplified expression like:

```
//a[@data-val='ma_signin']
```

so it won't be dependent on parents and ancestors.

Another possibility is that the element is in another frame so you will need to [switch to it](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo()) first.

If the element in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM) you will need again to switch the WebDriver context there using [JavaScriptExecutor.executeScript()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) function

In general using Selenium in conjunction with JMeter is not something you should be doing. References:

- [Selenium Performance Testing](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

  > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.
- [WebDriver Sampler Tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

  > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So you might rather want to invest into [configuring JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) than kicking off real browsers in multithreaded manner